# Css font weight in percentage

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

I have a requirement like below,

[image]

Here as you can see the `Body1` has a normal font which is easy to achieve, but the requirement for the `Body subtext` font is such that it should have **55% boldness** of `Body1` as can be seen in the pic above. How can I achieve the same?

PS: I tried font weight setting it between 100-400 but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Your example does not look like it has a different weight. It looks like it has a different opacity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in the picture the difference of boldness between Body 1 and Body subtext. If I understand well your question, font-weight doesn't accept direct percentage values, but since normal = 400, 55% boldness of normal is nearly 200 (actually is 220 but not accepted value).

However, if you tried 100 to 400 and it doesn't work, it's perhaps because that you didn't give it the right way.

Comment: This would be better added as a comment.

Comment: @NathanBrown He can not comment I guess... 'coz of low rep

Comment: sorry I can't comment, this is the first question I answered. And it is "she can't comment";)